# Condiciones para inserción de registros SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Tengo un problema muy grande. Estoy haciendo mediante dos procesos distintos la inserción de datos de facturación a dos tablas (encabezado y detalle).

El insert de los encabezados es la siguiente:

```
INSERT INTO T_FACTURACLI (IDFactura, FechaDocumento, NombreCliente, NIT, DireccionFacturacion, Folio, Subfolio,
                          Habitacion, Serie, NumeroDoc, IdVendedor, IDClienteIQware, DocType)
SELECT        IDFactura, FechaDocumento, NombreCliente, NIT, DireccionFacturacion, FOLIO, Subfolio, Habitacion, SERIE, NumeroDoc, IDVendor, CASE IDClienteIQware WHEN 'CF' THEN 0 END, DocType
FROM            POS_EDIFAC.dbo.V_InvoiceHeader
WHERE FechaDocumento = (SELECT CurrentHotelDate -1 FROM prProperty)
```

y el insert de los detalles es el siguiente:

```
INSERT INTO T_FACTURACLI_FILAS (IDFactura, Linea, FechaDocumento, Descripcion, IDTipoTransaccion, TipoTransaccion, ShortName, Total)
SELECT        IDFactura, Linea, FechaDocumento, Descripcion, IDTipoTransaccion, TipoTransaccion, ShortName, Total
FROM            POS_EDIFAC.dbo.V_InvoiceDetail
WHERE FechaDocumento = (SELECT CurrentHotelDate -1 FROM prProperty)
```

Por requerimientos del sistema contable he colocado una Foreign Key constraint en el campo IDFactura, por lo que no puedo insertar detalles cuando no existe el idfactura en la tabla de encabezado.

Mi pregunta es si hay alguna forma de validar en la inserción del detalle si el idfactura ya existe en la tabla de encabezado antes de insertar los detalles para que de esta forma salte los registros que no tengan un identificador ya guardado.

Answer (score 2):

podrías hacer uso del **"exists"** . `EXISTS(o NOT EXISTS)` está especialmente diseñado para verificar si algo existe y, por lo tanto, debería ser (y es) la mejor opción. Se detendrá en la primera fila que coincida.
Deberías hacer algo así:

```
 IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM POS_EDIFAC.dbo.V_InvoiceHeader WHERE IDFactura = ?)
    BEGIN
    -- Aquí ejecutas el código en el caso de que exista.
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
    -- Aquí ejecutas el código opcional en el caso de que NO exista.
    END
```

Para aprender mas de este operador te sugiero [hacer click aquí](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_exists.asp)

Espero que te ayude. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Lo que podrías hacer es decirle a tu consulta del detalle(V_InvoiceDetail) que te traiga solo los datos que estén en la tabla padre(V_InvoiceHeader), por ejemplo:

```
    INSERT INTO T_FACTURACLI_FILAS (IDFactura, Linea, FechaDocumento, Descripcion, 
    IDTipoTransaccion, TipoTransaccion, ShortName, Total)
    SELECT IDFactura, Linea, FechaDocumento, Descripcion, IDTipoTransaccion, 
    TipoTransaccion, ShortName, Total
    FROM POS_EDIFAC.dbo.V_InvoiceDetail
    WHERE FechaDocumento = (SELECT CurrentHotelDate -1 FROM prProperty) 
    AND IDFactura In (Select IDFactura From POS_EDIFAC.dbo.V_InvoiceHeader)
```

De esta manera te aseguras de que va a insertar solo las facturas que esten en la tabla padre, y las que no, las va a ignorar.